# Script editing in Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

How do I edit the script using firebug?

Comment: I retagged your question assuming that you meant javascript.

Comment: @Orbling: Since Firebug can be used to manipulate/"edit" the DOM, it's a fair question.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: It can not edit scripts though.

Comment: Actually you CAN change the script at runtime, use the Firebug console as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203779/how-to-edit-javascript-in-firebug-in-mozilla

Answer (score 4):

[You can't](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), though you *can* execute arbitrary statements in the console, and modify the value of variables from the Watch pane.

Comment: Beat me to it. Just sharing something from the mail list to confirm what you have said: http://old.nabble.com/Edit-Script---Is-it-possible--td22713964.html

Comment: Use the Firebug console as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203779/how-to-edit-javascript-in-firebug-in-mozilla

Answer (score 0):

You can edit HTML, debug javascript, watch and edit the variables, but you can't edit the script.