# only change edited javascript file in browser

Tags: javascript

I have heavy project with javascript and everytime i change one file i must refresh page and all file must get again from server and my handlebar render again and ...

how i can only change edited file in browser? and not touch other files?

i don't know, some thing like append new script to page with new `rev` to make it not cache

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bjs/framework/manifest.js?rev=1024"></script>
```

also i use `Mercurial`, `Emacs`, `Firefox` and there is no force for this tools. only i want know this can be happen. i find way to port to my tools

some things like CSS Reloader :: Add-ons for Firefox -> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-reloader/ for js and only edited js

ps: its local server but i have about 2mb file and after 10 or 20 time refresh my firefox come near crash

Comment: Why not just run this server locally? It makes for much faster development.

Comment: Sounds like you have lots of JavaScript and every time you make a small change, everything have to be reloaded. I suggest you break up your JavaScript into smaller files to reduce the need to reload everything.

Comment: @RayCheng i have many small file and i must have all of them to can see page. now how this can be help me to reduce load? tnx for your ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found somethings helpfull to answer my question

- Auto Reload :: Add-ons for Firefox ->
  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-reload/?src=search
- Browser extensions / General Use / Knowledge Base - LiveReload
  Support ->
  http://help.livereload.com/kb/general-use/browser-extensions
- Python LiveReload -> http://project.lepture.com/python-livereload/

with this plugin i can find some file changed. so i can run js script after change file and replace js file with new file. i thinks this is best way for developing

Answer (score 1):

For a particular interval, you can refresh the JavaScript Code using `setInterval()` and reload it again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sc = document.createElement('script');
    setInterval('sc.setAttribute("src", "script.js")', 5000);
</script>
```

Hope this helps or gives you an idea of what you need to do. :)

Comment: did you ever seen some thing after save file do this things?

Comment: See, actually for this to reflect, what I do is, I encapsulate all the code inside the `$(document).ready();` function. And when I add it dynamically, for every 10 seconds, I refresh the code using the method you said, but I use `?567465468` « The timestamp. Then I call the `$(document).ready();` function. I am using the code in my application for live notifications. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug, you can edit your js/css files on the fly, and/or using the javascript console, run code without refreshing the page. That is the only thing I could think of that might help. Take a look here [How to edit JavaScript in Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203779/how-to-edit-javascript-in-firebug-in-mozilla) to see how.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script tyep="text/javascript">

</script>

<script tyep="text/javascript">
 document.scripts[0].src="/static/js/bjs/framework/manifest.js?rev="+Math.random()
</script>
```

use Math.random() function get new rev everytime.

Comment: It includes the new script but doesn't refresh... Check my answer @user1374548

Comment: @Praveen Kumar  I said is just an example，It is important that the Math.Random ( function ) give new rev.I offer only an idea。